# How to rearrange $ H = \frac{1}{2}g \lambda^2 t^2 - \sqrt{2g\lambda^2 H_0}t + H_0$ for $\lambda$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am attempting to rearrange this equation to find an equation of the form $\lambda =$ and seem to have got stuck:
$$ H = \frac{1}{2}g \lambda^2 t^2 - \sqrt{2g\lambda^2 H_0}t + H_0$$

I started by square rooting $\lambda^2$ to give:
$$\sqrt{2gH_0}\lambda t = \frac{1}{2}g \lambda^2 t^2 + H_0 - H$$

I thought I could then divide by $\lambda$ to obtain:

$$\sqrt{2gH_0} t = \frac{1}{2}g \lambda t^2 + \frac{H_0 - H}{\lambda}$$

But from this point I am not sure how to proceed.

Is this an invalid method? Or is there a different way that is simpler? Or can I not rearrange this for $\lambda$ at all?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we know $\;\lambda\ge0\;$ , what you did is correct, so we have:

$$\frac12gt^2\,\lambda^2-\sqrt{2gH_0}t\,\lambda+H_0-H=0$$

The above is a quadratic in $\;\lambda\;$ so you can use the usual formula to obtain its roots:

$$\Delta=2gH_0t^2-2gt^2(H_0-H)=2gt^2H$$

and assuming $\;gH\ge0\;$, the above has *real* roots (otherwise you will have to deal with complex ones...), so

$$\lambda_{1,2}=\frac{\sqrt{2gH_0}\,t\pm\sqrt\Delta}{\frac12gt^2}$$

Observe that there are several things one must be careful with: we must have $\;gt\neq0\;$, for example.

Answer (score 0):

write $$\sqrt{2g\lambda^2H_0t}=\frac{1}{2}g\lambda^2t^2+H_0-H$$ and square the whole Thing
you will get
$$2g\lambda^2H_0t=\frac{1}{4}g^2\lambda^4t^4+(H_0-H)^2+2\cdot \frac{1}{2}g\lambda^2t^2(H_0-H)$$
then set $$\lambda^2=z$$ and solve a quadratic equation